# Swagger definition: $ref and required

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

so, I want to write a definition like this:

```
components:
    accuracy::
      $ref: '#/definitions/accuracy'
      required: false
```

and 'override' a required property. But the documentation says:

> Any sibling elements of a $ref are ignored. This is because $ref works
>   by replacing itself and everything on its level with the definition it
>   is pointing at.

So, is there any way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`required` is not a property attribute, it's an object attribute containing a list of required properties. So you should use:

```yaml
MyObject:
  type: object
  properties:
    accuracy:
      $ref: '#/definitions/accuracy'
  required:
    - accuracy
```